# How to escape the password for calls to wp_authenticate_username_password

Tags: php, wordpress

Apparently in wordpress the passwords are hashes of the users password, but with some characters escaped.  I've just discovered this as one of our users cannot log in via our custom API and his password contained single quote marks. I found this bug report: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/5278 discussing the problem.

However I cannot find any documentation on which characters are escaped.

I'd like to update our API so it injects the same characters as wordpress does when the user initially sets their password.

What function should I use on the password prior to passing it to wp_authenticate_username_password?